# I can connect to MongoDB, but when I create a cursor with iterable.iterator() I get com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException

Tags: java, mongodb

```
        String user = "readonly"; // the user name
        String database = "example"; // the name of the database in which the user is defined
        char[] password = "example".toCharArray(); // the password as a character array

        MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(user, database, password);

        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .credential(credential)
                .applyToSslSettings(builder -> builder.enabled(true))
                .applyToClusterSettings(builder -> 
                    builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress("example", 8989))))
                .build();

        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
        
        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("prefusion");
        
        System.out.println(db.getName());
        
        MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection("provenance");
        
        FindIterable<Document> iterable = coll.find();
        MongoCursor<Document> cursor = iterable.iterator();
        Document current;
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            current = cursor.next();
            System.out.println(current.getString("subject"));
            System.out.println(current.getString("predicate"));
            System.out.println(current.getString("object"));
            
        }

        cursor.close();
```

Every time I run this program, the database name gets printed but then I get the following error in the `MongoCursor<Document> cursor = iterable.iterator();` line:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=example:8989, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message}, caused by {javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake}, caused by {java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly}}]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:177)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.getDescription(SingleServerCluster.java:41)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.getConnectedClusterDescription(MongoClientDelegate.java:147)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.createClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:98)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.getClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:278)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:182)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:135)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:92)
    at edu.upf.taln.uima.dbpedia_generic.core.MongoDBReader.main(MongoDBReader.java:44)
```

The fact that at first it connects and it can print the database name implies that it's not a simple connection issue. Is it possible that the operation of creating the cursor "overloads" the database somehow?

I am using version 4.0.4 of `mongo-driver-sync`.

Comment: Why do you say the connection succeeded? Most likely it didn't.

Comment: Because then why would it be able to execute the `System.out.println(db.getName());` line? Surely you need to be able to connect to a database to get its name programatically?

Comment: You provided the database name on the previous line.

Comment: You are right about that, but if it wasn't connected at all in the first place, why doesn't it fail when I try to get the collection? Does Mongo allow you to get a collection if you're not connected?

Comment: Constructons do not perform i/o. https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring.rst#clients-do-no-i-o-in-the-constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to disable the SSL certification:

```
                .applyToSslSettings(builder -> builder.enabled(false))
```